# Subquery option to produce wanted output

Tags: mysql

Here's my query:

```
    select email_address, count(customer_id) AS order_count, sum((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)) AS order_total,
round(avg((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)),2) AS avg_order_total
from customers join orders 
using(customer_id)
join order_items 
using(order_id)
group by customer_id
having count(order_id) > 1 
order by round(avg((item_price - discount_amount) * (quantity)),2) desc
```

my output

[image: my output]

wanted output

[image: wanted output]

How can I use a subquery to produce the wanted output? Can't use limit BTW

Comment: Welcome. Please indent your query and eventually play with character case if your religion allows it. Also don't post links to png files. Instead write the output and wanted output in the question itself.

Comment: How are you choosing to exclude the middle record? Is it random? I see the desired result, but what is the desired logic to get there?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: This is just impossible to answer accurately without `sample data (for each table)`.  Trying to answer this is like being a blindfolded pilot in a sandstorm i.e. doomed to failure

Answer (score 0):

The following is a guess, does this work, and is it any better

```
SELECT
      c.customer_id
    , COUNT(o.customer_id) AS order_count
    , SUM((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)) AS order_total
    , ROUND(AVG((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)), 2) AS avg_order_total
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
INNER JOIN order_items oi ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
GROUP BY
      c.customer_id
HAVING COUNT(o.order_id) > 1
ORDER BY
      ROUND(AVG((oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount) * (oi.quantity)), 2) DESC
```

I am assuming these `item_price`, `discount_amount`, `quantity` are from the `order_items`  table, f that isn't true change the "oi." to the correct take alias.